# Name attribute does nothing? JSON Serialize

Tags: c#, json, mapping

I have a class ready to serialize a JSON object, my REST API returns an value called "api_key", but I want my attribute named "ApiKey", then I made this code:

```
    [DataContract]
    class JsonToken
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "api_key")]
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    }
```

I thought that "Name" value will map the values but doesn't occours.
Then I'd change my code to something like this, and now it works.

```
    [DataContract]
    class JsonToken
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string api_key{ get; set; }

    }
```

But I still want my attribute named "ApiKey", then, I have two questions:

1ª How can I turn my attibute named to "ApiKey" (and it works)?

2ª What Name attribute does, if it's not map the values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET project are you using? Is this an MVC project? Or is it a standard Web Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` class to do the serialisation - You may need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

```
JsonToken token = new JsonToken() { ApiKey = "Gunk" };

DataContractJsonSerializer jsx = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonToken));
string json = "";
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    jsx.WriteObject(ms, token);
    json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

There is no direct to string serialisation options, so you have to wrap it around a memory stream.  The above code should give

```
{"api_key":"Gunk"}
```